# replacing X axis values with labels and keeping order in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a large data frame that part of it looks like this:

```
data<-structure(list(b = c(-2.64, -2.184, -1.896, -1.874, -0.567, -0.454
), MLmisfit = c(-2.677, -1.92, -1.135, -0.512, -0.06, -0.048), 
    LzML = c(-1.145, -0.875, -0.562, -0.314, -0.074, -0.065), 
    HTML = c(-1.268, -0.935, -0.59, -0.305, -0.092, -0.08)), .Names = c("b", 
"MLmisfit", "LzML", "HTML"), row.names = c("Item12", "Item9", 
"Item3", "Item7", "Item4", "Item11"), class = "data.frame")
```

Using `qplot` with this syntax I could create the graph below:

```
qplot(b,value,data=melt(data,id='b'),geom=c('line','point'),group=variable,col=variable)
```

[image]

There are about 120 items in the data set so manual labeling is not feasible. I'm looking for a way to replace points on X axis with rownames of the data set as it's ordered. I tried to use `scale_x_discrete` but it didn't work.

Comment: If you want to use the rowname as the label at the x-value of each point, then add this to your plot: `scale_x_continuous(breaks=data$b, labels=rownames(data))`.

Comment: @eipi10 thanks for the hint but it distorted the grids.Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You mean you want "regular" major gridlines (and major axis labels?) plus you want axis labels for each point (and gridlines too?). Please provide more detail on exactly how you want the plot to look.

Comment: OK. Looking at the graph I posted, I want to replace the labels on X axis without damaging the vertical white gridlines. In your code those lines were stuck together at some points in the middle and labels were not readable.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options. I hope at least one of them works for you.

```
# Turn the rownames into a new data column
data$names = rownames(data)
```

Option 1: Place Item labels on the graph using `geom_text`

```
ggplot(data=melt(data, id.var=c("b","names")), aes(b, value)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=variable, colour=variable)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour=variable)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-3.1,0.2)) +
  geom_text(data=data, aes(label=names, x=b), 
            y=-2.85, size=4, angle=-90, hjust=0)
```

Option 2: Add Item labels as axis labels, but use `geom_vline` to cover up the unwanted vertical grid lines

```
ggplot(data=melt(data, id.var=c("b","names")), aes(b, value)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-3.1,0.2)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(data$b,-1,-2), labels=c(data$names,-1,-2), 
                     minor_breaks=seq(-3,0,0.5)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=data$b, colour=rgb(0,0,0,0.12)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=variable, colour=variable)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour=variable))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for **not to print x label according to "b" value**. Then try this

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape)
data["new_variable"] <- c(1:6)
data <- subset(data, select=-b)
qplot(new_variable,value,data=melt(data,id='new_variable'),geom=c('line','point'),group=variable,col=variable, xlab = "Items")+ scale_x_continuous(breaks=data$new_variable, labels=rownames(data)) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = .5))
```

[image]

Comment: This is nice but why the graph looks different than mine?? I think it looks the b is converted to factor.

Comment: Because of the close values of **b** (like -1.896 and -1.874) your graphs was looking congested and I have added a new_variable, which is list of integer (1 to 6). So, the new graph has nothing to do with `b` value, our new x-axis is `new_variable` and x labels are coming from `row.names`.